# Using Ternary in Vue Template

Tags: vue.js, conditional-operator

Is it possible to use ternary condition in a Vue template to return HTML, similar to React render function?

```
<some-vue-component :someProp="someVal" />
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
// some-vue-component template file
{{someProp == true ? <h1>Hello</h1> : <h1>Bye</h1>}}
```

Do I need to use `v-if`?

```
// some-vue-component template file
<div>
  <div v-if="someProp === true">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <h1>Bye</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

Everything output using `{{ ... }}` will be escaped, so you can't include HTML tags.

In the example you gave you'd just move the `<h1>` outside the `{{ ... }}`:

```html
<h1>{{ someProp ? 'Hello' : 'Bye' }}</h1>
```

More generally you'd use `v-if`:

```html
<h1 v-if="someProp">Hello</h1>
<h2 v-else>Bye</h2>
```

Note also that `v-if` can be placed on a `<template>` tag if you don't want it to add an extra element to the finished DOM:

```html
<template v-if="someProp">Hello</template>
<strong v-else>Bye</strong>
```

At a pinch there's also `v-html` but you should avoid using that if at all possible. It allows you to inject HTML directly but that's rarely necessary as templates can handle the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: Yes, on your last example with the `template` tag, I wanted to have ternary within there to either show a loading component or the default component set up, but I don't have a `template` tag wrapper, but it seems like Vue docs wants you to use render function for what I am trying to achieve. Otherwise they suggest using the `v-if`.

Comment: @henhen I'm afraid I'm not following the scenario you're describing. Nothing you've said so far makes me think that a `render` function is necessary.

Comment: I think Vue docs suggests using Render function if you will have multiple `v-if/else` for showing different views